# Find names, diagues, etc using regex and python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a dialogue txt file like below

```
PETER: Hello, anyone here?
PETER: Ok. I'll Go in.
Umm...Where is Bob?
(Sigh)
BOB: Boo!
PETER: I wasn't surprised, Bob.
```

I want to change it to several files by Character names like below:
PETER.txt:

```
PETER: Hello, anyone here?
PETER: Ok. I'll Go in.
Umm...Where is Bob?
(Sigh)
PETER: I wasn't surprised, Bob.
```

BOB.txt:

```
BOB: Boo!
```

My own dialog is much longer than this and it has many characters. How can I do this using regex?

Comment: Are you sure this is possible. some sentences have PETER:, some haven’t. please tell me what’s algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general solution using `re.findall` which generates a single list of all conversation entries, sorted by the person:

```py
inp = """PETER: Hello, anyone here?
PETER: Ok. I'll Go in.
Umm...Where is Bob?
(Sigh)
BOB: Boo!
PETER: I wasn't surprised, Bob.
"""

matches = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+:.*?(?=[A-Z]+:\s|$)', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
matches.sort(key=lambda x: re.sub(r'^([A-Z]+).*', r'\1', x))
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['BOB: Boo!\n',
 "PETER: I wasn't surprised, Bob.",
 'PETER: Hello, anyone here?\n',
 "PETER: Ok. I'll Go in.\nUmm...Where is Bob?\n(Sigh)\n"]
```

It isn't clear whether or not you also want code for how to generate the files, but it would be easy enough to iterate the above list and then write out to separate files based on the speaker.